# Burninate [expand]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

The tag [expand](/questions/tagged/expand) seems to serve no purpose. Most of the questions tagged this have to do with a HTML/CSS/Javascript-related problem. This tag seems to be very vague and serves no purpose. We could not possibly benefit from having such a general tag.

In short, **burninate the [expand](/questions/tagged/expand) tag.** Thanks.

Comment: I agree, it is vague and doesn't provide any information.

Answer (score 1):

The tag seems used in questions about a UI element that can be visually expanded. The questions are someway related to expanding the element, but that tag doesn't add anything to the question. It is enough to describe what happens when visually expanding the element; that fact doesn't need to be captured in a tag. Are there users who avoid reading the question because they see [expand](/questions/tagged/expand) used from the question, and they are not able to answer that kind of questions?

Comment: I wouldn't think so.